# Unusual html form

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to create a contact form but the layout is not like any other layout.
I am having problems designing the layout

`contact form`

```
Contact Name
[......]     [........]      [..........]
firstname    middlename       Lastname

Phone
[.......]            [.......]
 areacode               phone
```

```
 <form>
    <div class="form-all">
        <div class="form-all">
    <ul class="form-section">
      <li class="form-line" id="id_69">
        <label class="form-label-top" id="label_69" for="input_69">
          CONTACT NAME<span class="form-required">*</span>
        </label>
        <div id="cid_69" class="form-input-wide">
        <span class="form-sub-label-container">
        <input class="form-textbox validate[required]" type="text" size="10" name="q69_contactName69[first]" id="first_69">
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="first_69" id="sublabel_first"> First Name </label></span><span class="form-sub-label-container"><input class="form-textbox" type="text" size="10" name="q69_contactName69[middle]" id="middle_69">
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="middle_69" id="sublabel_middle"> Middle Name </label></span><span class="form-sub-label-container"><input class="form-textbox validate[required]" type="text" size="15" name="q69_contactName69[last]" id="last_69">
            <label class="form-sub-label" for="last_69" id="sublabel_last"> Last Name/Surname </label></span>
        </div>
      </li>
```

something similar to http://www.esvalmodels.com/order_form_jotform.html

Comment: What do you got so far, what isn't working?

Comment: Look up the [display: inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) CSS property & value.

Comment: I've added a JS fiddle in case you didn't manage to work this out yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TGH suggests, you should use `float:left;`. On `span` elements add `display:block;` to get it to work.

```
.form-sub-label-container {
    display:"block";
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XX4ju/

Answer (score 1):

Use divs with float left css style.

```
<div style="float:left">FirstName</div><div style="float:left">MiddleName</div>
```